# Calculating midpoint, initial bearing, and distance in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

SOLVED:

I'm trying to write a script that calculates the distance, bearing, and mid-point given a pair of lat lon coords.

I found the formula's easily enough, but I'm getting the wrong answers. It might just be a math mistake, but I've looked it over multiple times and I'm missing something.
I'm following this website's formulas: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-nomodule.html

Here's what I get, output is dist, bearing, midpoint lat, midpoint long

script.bash 1 -80 -3 -79.2

453.58,158.22,68.1258,95.390

this is what I should get:

script.bash 1 -80 -3 -79.2

453.6 168.7 -1 -79.6

So, distance looks good. But the others are all off. Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

lat1=$1
lat2=$3
lon1=$2
lon2=$4

#some basic info

R=6371

lat1r=`echo "$lat1*3.14159/180" | bc -l`
lat2r=`echo "$lat2*3.14159/180" | bc -l`
lon1r=`echo "$lon1*3.14159/180" | bc -l`
lon2r=`echo "$lon2*3.14159/180" | bc -l`

dLat=`echo "$lat2r - $lat1r" | bc -l`
dLon=`echo "$lon2r - $lon1r" | bc -l`

#Distance calculations
a=`echo "-s ($dLat/2) * -s ($dLat/2) + -c ($lat1r) * -c ($lat2r) * -s ($dLon/2) * -s ($dLon/2)" | bc -l`
c1=`echo "sqrt($a) " | bc -l`
c2=`echo "sqrt(1 - $a)" | bc -l`
cat=`echo "$c1,$c2"| awk -F',' '{ print atan2($1,$2) }'`
c=`echo "2*$cat" | bc -l`
d=`echo "$R*$c" | bc -l`

#Bearing calculation 

y=`echo "-s ($dLon) * -c ($lat2r)" | bc -l`
x=`echo "-c ($lat1r) * -s ($lat2r) - -s ($lat1r) * -c ($lat2r) * -c ($dLon)" | bc -l`

brng=`echo "$y,$x"| awk -F',' '{ print atan2($1,$2) }'`
brn=`echo "$brng * 180 / 3.14159" | bc -l`
echo "$brng * 180 / 3.14159" 

#Mid point calculation

Bx=`echo "-c ($lat2r) * -c ($dLon)" | bc -l`
By=`echo "-c ($lat2r) * -s ($dLon)" | bc -l`
atc1=`echo " -s ($lat1r) + -s ($lat2r)" | bc -l`
atc2=`echo " sqrt( ( -c ($lat1r) + $Bx )^2 + $By^2 ) "  | bc -l`

latmidr=`echo "$atc1,$atc2"| awk -F',' '{ print atan2($1,$2) }'`
latmid=`echo "$latmidr * 180 / 3.14159" | bc -l`

atc3=$By
atc4=`echo " -c ($lat1r) + $Bx" | bc -l`

lonmidr=`echo "$atc3,$atc4"| awk -F',' '{ print atan2($1,$2) }'`
lonmid=`echo "$lonmidr * 180 / 3.14159" | bc -l`

echo $d,$brn,$latmidr,$lonmid
```

Comment: Just ... why? Use a language that actually does floating-point arithmetic instead of forking entire processes to handle a single operation.

Comment: A lack of any actual training in scripting? I like the awk solution, didn't realize you could do so much with awk.

Comment: Don't add a working solution to your question at all. Those interested can see it in Ed's answer.

Comment: I changed it back.

Comment: A shell is an environment from which to manipulate (create/destroy) files and processes and call tools with a language to sequence those calls. If you want to do anything more than that, e.g. manipulate text or math calculations then you need to find out which tool does whatever it is you want to do (start looking at awk first as it's the only such tool that comes as standard on all UNIX installations) and use it rather than trying to do it using shell constructs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a completely inappropriate job for a shell script, you should have done it as a single awk (or similar, e.g. perl, ruby, python) script. Btw naming a variable the same as a command (`cat`) obfuscates your code and makes it more error prone.

Here's what your starting point **should** be (check the math/conversions as I almost certainly didn't always interpret what you were trying to do when piping strings with `-s` and `-c` to bc etc. correctly as I was guessing):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v lat1="$1" -v lat2="$3" -v lon1="$2" -v lon2="$4" '
BEGIN {
    #some basic info

    pi = 3.14159
    R  = 6371

    lat1r = lat1 * pi / 180
    lat2r = lat2 * pi / 180
    lon1r = lon1 * pi / 180
    lon2r = lon2 * pi / 180

    dLat = lat2r - lat1r
    dLon = lon2r - lon1r

    #Distance calculations
    a   = sin(dLat/2) * sin(dLat/2) + cos(lat1r) * cos(lat2r) * sin(dLon/2) * sin(dLon/2)
    c1  = sqrt(a)
    c2  = sqrt(1 - a)
    cat = atan2(c1,c2)
    c   = 2 * cat
    d   = R * c

    #Bearing calculation
    x = cos(lat1r) * sin(lat2r) - sin(lat1r) * cos(lat2r) * cos(dLon)
    y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2r)

    brng = atan2(y,x)
    brn  = brng * 180 / pi
    print brng * 180 / pi

    #Mid point calculation

    Bx = cos(lat2r) * cos(dLon)
    By = cos(lat2r) * sin(dLon)
    atc1 = sin(lat1r) + sin(lat2r)
    atc2 = sqrt( (cos(lat1r) + Bx )^2 + By^2 )

    latmidr = atan2(atc1,atc2)
    latmid  = latmidr * 180 / pi

    atc3 = By
    atc4 = cos(lat1r) + Bx

    lonmidr = lon1r + atan2(atc3,atc4)
    lonmid  = lonmidr * 180 / pi

    print d, brn, latmid, lonmid
}
'
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh 1 -80 -3 -79.2
168.696
453.581 168.696 -1.00002 -79.6002
```

Comment: The -s and -c are sine and cos respectively. I'm trying this out but getting a completely different answer. If I get it back to my original results or the correct result I'll update my post.

Comment: So you just want to call sin() and cos() on the values after each -s and -c? OK I updated my "answer". Again, check that what I interpreted and wrote is what you intended. You should find that far easier to debug than your original shell script.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the error now and its working.

Comment: I think if you change the line with lonmidr to     lonmidr = lon1r + atan2(atc3,atc4) then the script will be working correctly, that was my original error and pretty sure they only thing I changed from this.

Comment: Whoops, I changed the print line as well, third value should be latmid, not latmidr, that was the radians value. I get 453.581 168.696 -1.00002 -79.6002.

Comment: Updated, produces the desired output now.